Переадресация запросов из внешней сети в VPN
Нужно решить такую проблему, есть телефон с сервером фтп и хттп. Есть оператор связи который не даёт белый статический ИП. Так же есть сервер на котором крутится виртуальная машина на Debian. Я могу пробросить запросы из внешней сети внутрь виртуальной машины, так же могу подключиться к виртуальной машине через vpn. Вопрос такой, как внутри виртуальной машины сделать переадресацию внешних запросов на порт XXX в то самое впн соединение чтобы запрос дошел до телефона. Возможно есть софт какой-нибудь? Грубо говоря вопрос в том как пользователь просто вводя в браузере название сайта (домен у меня есть и привязан к ИП адресу) попасть на мой сервер в телефоне?
